# git: after checking out an old commit, how can i see the next commits?

Tags: git

I did checkout to an old commit.

Now I want to list the later commits to that commit I'm mentioning, showing that commit the first in the list. How can i do that? using some option in 'git log'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're on branch `master` this will show the commits from the currently checked out revision to the tip of the branch:

```
git log ..master
```

To include the currently checkout out revision use:

```
git log HEAD^..master
```

Comment: THANKS! you give the clue.. What i need is "git log ..master --reverse".

Comment: or "git log --reverse HEAD^..master" to include the current one.